# Как решить проблему с http запросом на python к API

Tags: python, requests

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so2.py", line 5, in <module>
    account_info = standoff.get_account_info()
  File "C:\Portside\FACEIT - Main - копия\core\standoff.py", line 13, in get_ac
ount_info
    return requests.get(f"{self.api}/accounts/{self.user_id}",headers=self.head
rs).json()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packa
es\requests\models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

У меня есть класс и в нем различные функции которые выплняют http запрос на API игры standoff 2, в результате запроса выходит выше указанная ошибка, кто может, пожалуйста подскажите в чем заключается проблема и как ее решить!

Функция:

```
class StoreStandoff2:
def __init__(self, user_id: int) -> None:
    self.api = "https://store.standoff2.com/api/v1"
    self.headers = {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.5060.114 Safari/537.36"
    }
    self.user_id = user_id

def get_account_info(self) -> dict:
    return requests.get(f"{self.api}/accounts/{self.user_id}",headers=self.headers).json()
```

Вызов функции:

```
    from core import standoff

standoff = standoff.StoreStandoff2(user_id="75903569")

account_info = standoff.get_account_info()
print(account_info)
```

Comment: Смотрите в корень requests.get(f"{self.api}/accounts/{self.user_id}",headers=self.headers) что реально приходить от сервера может там не json, а так же проверте статус код от запроса.

Comment: Авторизацию прошли в классе StoreStandoff2? API откуда взяли?